# How do configure Skype For Business to not start when macOS starts?

Tags: macos, skype

Skype For Business 16.2.145 automatically starts and sign's in when my machine starts.

The usual solutions for Skype don't work for Skype for Business. I cannot change this setting in the dock or in the app's preferences.

How do I change this setting?

Comment: Have you checked system preferences - accounts - login items?

Comment: @grgarside This is not a duplicate because I am referring to Skype for Business not Skype and that answer does not work for Skype For Business

Comment: @RobdeJonge thanks mate. Your answer actually worked. If you set it as the answer I will mark it correct

Comment: @TheLearner You just said it's not a duplicate, so I've re-opened your question, but now you say the login items solution works, which makes it a duplicate?

Comment: The answer in the duplicated question does not work. The answer that @RobdeJonge gave does work. If you look at the 2 answers they both different approaches to doing the same thing. Sadly only Rob's answer actually works. What do you want me to say mate?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Check **System Preferences** - **Accounts** for Sierra, **Users and Groups** for Catalina - **Login Items** and make sure it's added there.

**Alternative 1:**

Open the context menu on the icon in the dock -> options -> uncheck "open at login".

**Alternative 2:**

Open the terminal and type `launchctl list | grep skype`.

Then use `sudo launchctl remove <name from the previous output>` to prevent it from starting at login.

Comment: This is correct, but to clarify for macos Sierra - if you don't want Skype for Business to open automatically go to System Preferences > Users & Groups > Current User > Login Items. If Skype for Business is listed, select it, and then click - to remove it.  It won't start anymore.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Skype for Business is not listed there yet is still launches on login.

Comment: It was listed for me, but not checked. I went ahead and removed it from the list, but that will probably not have any effect on it.

Comment: So what I did was used terminal. Found it with `launchctl list | grep skype`. Then removed it with `sudo launchctl remove com.skype.skype.shareagent`.

Comment: Of all the applications that I've installed this year, why is it not surprising that only Skype thinks it's important enough to enjoy a unilateral login startup...

Comment: @pthurmond - isn't that for "Regular Skype" rater than "Skype for Business". Both are on my system and it's just the business one I want to evict.

Comment: Like @Owen implied. It's disgusting the delusions of grandeur some of these products have.

Comment: @Patrick recent version uses upper Skype prefix so the command should be `launchctl list | grep -i skype` which means case insensitive search

Comment: @IlliaDanko They are trying hard not to let us prevent Skype from starting on boot. For me nothing related to `Skype` shows up when I type `launchctl list` however, Skype keeps starting up on boot, which is, quite frankly, very frustrating. Why haven't they asked me if I want it to start up automatically?!